# The construction outer semidirect product from two groups.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

**Problem:** Let $N$ and $H$ be any group and let $\theta \colon H \rightarrow \text{Aut}(N)$ is a homomorphism. The the set
$$G = \{(x,h) \mid x \in N, h \in H\},$$
is a group with operation defined as follow: for all $(x_1,h_1) \in G$ and $(x_2,h_2) \in G$,
$$(x_1,h_1)(x_2,h_2) = (x_1 \theta_{h_1} (x_2), h_1 h_2).$$
Denote $N_0 = \{(x,1) \mid x \in N\}$ and $H_0 = \{(1,h) \mid h \in H\}$. Then $N_0 \cong N$, $H_0 \cong H$ and $G$ is an inner semidirect product of $N_0$ by $H_0$. Moreover
$$(1,h)(x,1)(1,h)^{-1} = (\theta_h (x),1),$$
for all $x \in N$ and $h \in H$.

**My proof:**
To prove that $G$ is a group, we have to check three conditions in the definition of a group.

Firstly, the operation is associative. $\forall (x_i,h_i) \in G, i = 1,2,3$. $$[(x_1,h_1)(x_2,h_2)](x_3,h_3) = [x_1 \theta_{h_1} (x_2), h_1 h_2](x_3,h_3) = (x_1 \theta_{h_1} (x_2) \theta_{h_1 h_2}(x_3),h_1 h_2 h_3)$$
$$(x_1,h_1)[(x_2,h_2)(x_3,h_3)] = (x_1,h_1)[x_2 \theta_{h_2} (x_3),h_2 h_3] = (x_1 \theta_{h_1}(x_2 \theta_{h_2}(x_3)),h_1 h_2 h_3) = (x_1 \theta_{h_1}(x_2) \theta_{h_1 h_2}(x_3),h_1 h_2 h_3) = [(x_1,h_1)(x_2,h_2)](x_3,h_3).$$

Secondly, the identity element. Let $e$ be an identity element of $G$, $e = (e_N,e_H)$ since for any $(x,h) \in G$ we have 
$$e (x,h) = (e_N,e_H)(x,h) = (e_N \theta_{e_H}(x),e_H h) = (e_N x, e_H h) = (x,h) = (x e_N, h e_H) = (x \theta_h(e_N),h e_H) = (x,h)(e_N,e_H).$$

Finally, $(x,h)^{-1} = ((\theta_{h^{-1}}(x))^{-1},h^{-1})$ since
$$(x,h)((\theta_{h^{-1}}(x))^{-1},h^{-1}) = (x \theta_h (\theta_{h^{-1}}(x^{-1})),h h^{-1}) = (e_N,e_H)$$

To prove that $N_0,H_0$ are subgroups of $G$ and $N_0 \triangleleft G$, we do

$(x,1),(y,1) \in N_0, (x,1)(y,1) = (xy,1) \in N_0$, prove similarly for $H$, so we conclude that $N,H$ are subgroups of $G$.

$$(x,h)(x,1)(x^{-1},h^{-1}) = (x \theta_h(x),h)((\theta_h(x))^{-1},h^{-1}) = (x \theta_h(x) \theta_h ((\theta_h(x))^{-1}),1) = (x \theta_h (x) (x^{-1}),1) = (x,1),$$
so $N_0 \triangleleft G$.

$N_0 \cap H_0 = \{1\}$ since $1 = (1,1)$ is both in $N_0$ and $H_0$.

For each element $(x,h) \in G$ can be written uniquely in the form $(x,h) = (x,1)(1,h)$. So $G$ is an inner semidirect product of $N_0$ by $H_0$.

Please check my proof and do I have to prove that $(1,h)(x,1)(1,h)^{-1} = (\theta_h (x),1)$?

Comment: You did not show that $N$ is an inner semidirect product of $N_0$ and $H_0$. You only showed that $(G,\circ)$ is a group with the new composition $\circ$. And yes, for this we could need that $\theta$ is induced by conjugation.

Comment: Yes, I see. The information in the hypothesis seems like the difinition of an inner senidirect product, so could we conclude immediately that is an inner semidirect product of $N_0$ by $H_0$?

Comment: This depends on what you are allowed to use. If the inner semidirect product was only defined by saying $G=NQ$, $N\cap Q=1$, $N$ normal, it is not enough.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have edited my proof.

Comment: Your argument for the inverse is not quite right... you go from $(\theta_h(x))^{-1}$ to $\theta_{h^{-1}}(x^{-1})$. That's not correct. $\theta_h(x)^{-1} = \theta_h(x^{-1})$, but it need not be $\theta_{h^{-1}}(x^{-1})$. It's an easy fix, but right now it is incorrect.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the inverse is $\theta_{h^{-1}} (x^{-1})$ since $\theta_{h^{-1}}(x^{-1}) = h^{-1} x^{-1} (h^{-1})^{-1} = h^{-1} x^{-1} h$.

Comment: @Minh: Yes; though the "since" is wrong until you finish proving that the automorphism will correspond to conjugation. That is, you can't use this argument to justify it *while* trying to prove you get a group which is isomorphic to the internal semidirect product.

Comment: @Minh: And I note that it is still wrong the post; I'm talking about lines 11 and 12 in your proof.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see, it's must be $x\theta_{h}(\theta_h(x)^{-1}),h^{-1} = x\theta_{h}(\theta_h(x^{-1}),h^{-1}$. But how can we calculate this equation?

Comment: You don’t. That’s the point. Your assertion about the inverse is wrong. $(x,h)^{-1}$ is not $(\theta_h(x)^{-1},h^{-1})$. The correct statement is that $(x,h)^{-1}=(\theta_{h^{-1}}(x^{-1}),h^{-1})$.

Comment: Aha! I give a wrong assertion, but use the right inverse element in calculation. Thank you!